# Bootstrap datepicker UI issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've been using bootstrap datepicker for a while now. But I'm encountering a glitch on the UI side when the datepicker is being displayed. I'm not sure what is causing this. I checked everything even, updated my datepicker.css file and bootstrap-datepicker.js file from this [link](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Here's its current UI:

[image]

I'm expecting this kind of UI

[image]

Any ideas what's causing this? Thanks

Comment: can you show css what you had changed?

Comment: Inspect the element style using firebug or chrome bowser. It must be use of same class name for another thead td elements(table).

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava the css I use to changed my existing ones is found in the link http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/. I'm not sure if I get you right.

Comment: it means some other class is overriding bootstrap css

Comment: @Antony Inspected it and it seems that the only styles that affect the datepicker are from datepicker.css and the form-control.

Comment: Can you able to find the color? (i think #CD5257?) from your css files.

Comment: That was spot on! Commented it out and it works, it's weird though, it is set to table thead. But this field is not inside of any tables or theads.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.datepicker td, .datepicker th{background:#fff !important}
```